# last_activity_date meaning on /questions route

Tags: support, caching

I would like to add a cache layer to my app for questions, answers and comments.
The `last_activity_date` parameter on [/questions](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=questions) route seems a valid candidate (probably the [only way available](https://stackapps.com/questions/1028/why-does-the-api-lack-proper-http-cache-control-headers))
The help says:

```
"last_activity_date": {
     "description": "last time this post had any activity",
     "values": "unix epoch date, range [0, 253,402,300,799]",
     "optional": true
 }
```

What do you mean with **any activity**?
What kind of events modify this date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity is defined as, "whatever the site considers Activity."  Yeah...

More usefully, the current list is:

- edits (on the post themselves, and on an answer a question owns)
- opening a bounty
- a new answer
- initial creation

Basically, if it "bumps" a question its activity.

Comment: @Kevin uhm, as suspected it does not consider the comments. Do you know where to look at this information? I would like to be sure that people using StackPrinter print also the new comments.

Comment: @systempuntoout - query /posts/{id}/comments.  It'll accept a set of mixed question and answer ids, and has a creation sort (with associated min/max parameters).  Comment edits will be missed, but those are exceedingly rare (and excepting moderators/developers, can only occur within 5 minutes of a comments creation; so you can grab them with a a modifier on `min`).

Comment: @Kevin well, vectorized parameters are limited, isn't it? Your solution won't work for questions with hundreds of answers :(

Comment: @systemputoout - if you're looking to keep a copy of SO up to date, it is rather difficult.  If you're looking to keep a small subset (say, the last 100 q/a's printed) its perfectly tractable.

Comment: @Kevin yes, the last 100 q/a's printed are enough. But how could I achieve that if vectorized parameter has an upper limit? (more than one query just to check if comments are changed is out of discussion, in that case I would give up the caching idea)

Comment: @systempuntoout - the limit on vectorized ids is 100... maybe I'm not following, but it seems to me if you're already tracking the last hundred total question and answers (that is # q's + # a's = 100) printed it should just be 1 API query to get any new/modified (excepting moderator modifications) comments on them.

Comment: @Kevin moved the topic [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/1746/how-to-check-if-a-given-question-is-changed)