# How to check if a given question is changed

Tags: support, dev-tip, questions, caching

What is the fastest way to check if a question is changed using the API calls?
For my purpose (a cache), a question is considered changed if:

- A new comment is added to the question or to any of its answers
- It had any new [activity](https://stackapps.com/questions/1742/last-activity-date-meaning-on-questions-route)

What is the fastest way to get this check?

<sup>* the check should work also for questions with hundreds of answers</sup>

Comment: Of the 1,000,000+ questions on SO, less than a 100 have received more than 100 answers.  Less than 1%, and that's assuming none of those answers were ever deleted.  Its a really uncommon case, probably deserving of special treatment.  The average question receives 2 answers, with over 80% of all questions receiving (again, assuming no deletions) 5 or fewer answers.

Comment: The last such question asked was [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875533), which was closed.  Policy has changed over SO's lifetime to strongly discourage such questions.

Comment: @Kevin I just give up, too awkward to develop at the moment. Thanks for the stats.

Comment: hey sys, as @kev says and as I have noticed, bloated answer/comment counts are rare. I would think that this is a pretty useful case even with the corners. If I get some time this week I will fire up the soapi.js2 dev and bang out an exemplar for future reference.

Comment: @Sky keep in mind that bloated questions are the meat of StackPrinter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working on another API recently so I may be a bit dull but my first impression is that the path of least resistance is to

- pull your question(s) with answers and comments disregarding activity/creation filter (use max page size)
- compare last activity date of the question. this will include new answers and edits on both the question and answers - if bumped you have your answer - pass go
- compare comment count on the question and then each answer - if any have changed you have your answer - pass go

  - an obvious but unlikely hole here is if a comment is deleted and a comment is added resulting in an unchanged comment count. If this is a concern, compare comment_id

In terms of efficiency, this entails 1 (large payload) request and single iterated nested control structure for up to 100 questions <sup>*</sup>. One advantage is that if you pull with body=true, you already have your updated information.

Not as efficient as a last_activity_date that included comment activity but you work with what you have.

<sup>* This will likely break down for abnormal posts that contain >100 answers or posts with >100 comments. The only way I have found to fetch these is to perform distinct multipage pulls for answers and comments for each question, to which you would then apply the above criteria.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, here is my conclusion: too many steps to follow for something that should be straightforward instead. I give up for now, I really don't want wasting my time to build this kind of clunky check. Hope to see a good caching strategy provided by the API in the future.